# Running a shell script to get correct process count

Tags: linux, shell, grep, ps

I am trying to run the below shell script `test.sh`

```
$service=$1
$count=`ps -ef |grep -i "$service" |grep -v grep | wc -l`
echo "$count"
```

Command: `sh test.sh abcde`

I am expecting the script to output 0 but it gives me 1.

PS: I will be running this script using shell_exec from a php file and input to script will be array elements from php file

Comment: What are the intermediate results?

Comment: Consider using [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)

Comment: `service="$1"; count=$(pgrep "$service" | wc -l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `1` because the output of `ps -ef` include the command

```
sh test.sh abcde
```

and this is matched when you do `grep -i "abcde"`. You need to filter this out for the same reason you filter out `grep`, so change

```
grep -v grep
```

to

```
grep -E -v 'grep|test\.sh'
```